# React Native Maps Overlapping Marker

Tags: react-native, markerclusterer, react-native-maps

I use `React-Native-Maps` and my map marker pins that overlap each other spring apart gracefully when i click them, so can i pick the one wanted?

I've used [This library](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) for the web side.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are libraries that do this but normally it is implemented by adjusting the zoom level. Is that a possible solution or do you need to move the pins apart at the current zoom level?

If you want to move them apart at the current zoom level they could push into other pins and make the issue worse. You might be better off doing a bounding box search around whatever pin gets the click event and opening a popup to make a selection from any results in the box.