# Can I use OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with react-native-maps?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps, markerspiderfier

I am using `react-native-maps`, with `react-native-maps-super-cluster` to cluster markers next to each other, this works great when zoomed out but, I have some markers that are overlapping one over others at max zoom.

`OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier` resolves this on [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555877/can-i-use-overlappingmarkerspiderfier-with-react-google-maps) but, I haven't had luck on finding for react native.
[React Native Maps Overlapping Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52520140/react-native-maps-overlapping-marker)

Is there something similar for `react-native-maps`?

**EDIT**

This is what I have come up with at first, separate overlapping markers on a circumference. [overlapping markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amTb1.png) => [separated markers on circumference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCQ4m.png)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?